# ValueError resizing an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, resize

I have a small python script, and I always run into an error:

```
ValueError: cannot resize an array references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function
```

**Code:**

```
points = comp.findall('Points')              # comp is a parsed .xml
diffvals = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
diffvals.resize(len(points),8)
```

But there are two things I do not understand:

1. I only get this error when I use debugger.
2. I have another script with identical code, and everything works fine. I checked this with debugger, all values, data types and so on are identical (except the memory addresses of course)

I have no idea what I could possibly do to resolve this.

Comment: normally this error emerges when you do something along the lines of `c=np.arange(10, dtype=float);a=c;c.resize(20)`. is that your real code?

Comment: also, does `diffvals.resize(len(points),8, refcheck=False)` work?

Comment: since it's not trivial to reproduce the problem, post stripped down but *complete* code.

Comment: @Carson yes this works! but diffvals IS NOT referencing any other array. I do not do anything like `diffvals = other_diffvals_array`, The only thing I could possibly imagine is that np.arange() returns a reference. but this is nonsense, because in the 2nd script, everything works fine

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I do not have the permission to post the complete code.

Comment: @Zero: nobody cares about your *complete* code, and you should *never* post it. what we need is a code that is *complete* in the sense that it's enough (without any alteration) to reproduce the problem, no undefined variables, missing headers, stuff like that... if the xml part is not relevant, get rid of it, etc...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but I don't know how to reproduce the problem. I have by now copied my not working python script (the text), and put it into a new python file. this works. and I copied my working python script (again the text of it) and put it into a new python file, and suddenly, this does not work. I don't see any pattern.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot resize NumPy arrays that share data with another array in-place using the `resize` method by default. Instead, you can create a new resized array using the `np.resize` function:

```
np.resize(a, new_shape)
```

or you can disable reference checking using:

```
a.resize(new_shape, refcheck=False)
```

The likely reason you are only seeing it with a debugger is that the debugger references the array to e.g. print it. Also, the debugger may not store references to temporary arrays before you assign them into a variable, which probably explains why the other script works.

Comment: "You cannot resize NumPy arrays that share data with another array in-place" -> where does my numpy array share data with another array?

Comment: @ZerO, the debugger (and the interpreter for that matter) make temporary copies. You can see this by running the following in the interpreter: `>>> a = np.arange(10, dtype=float)`
`>>> a`
`array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])`
`>>> a.resize(1,5)`

Comment: but this does not explain why 1st code throws an error, while 2nd code works fine. both with debugger

Comment: @ZerO, you haven't shown the second code, but my guess is that it doesn't store the intermediary array in a variable that the debugger would touch and reference. E.g. this works in the interpreter: `>>> a = np.arange(10, dtype=float).resize(1,5)`, because the interpreter doesn't "see" the intermediate value.

Comment: I have shown it. it is exactly the same. I checked this, they are identical.

Comment: @ZerO, is both the code and the data really identical? In that case it's very weird. Either way, I've added another workaround to the answer.

Comment: yep the data is identical. this workaround works nice. but I still cannot figure out why it say reference in one code and no reference in another code

Comment: Are there breakpoints or other debugger flags in either of the codes? That can be sufficient for the debugger to change behaviour.

Comment: Thx, I understand error message, but can't understand why its raised. Yes it's debugger.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
a = a.copy()
```

before resizing

Comment: This works. Can you explain why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the bugger references the array to other place,and there is nothing while the code is running.you can change the code to:

```
diffvals.resize((len(points),8), refcheck = False)
```

when refcheck = False,when the fuction--resize works, reference count will not be checked, and then it is successful.